# Xfce, panel, item, windows button, add icon for specific application

Tags: icons, xfce, window, panel

**What I need:**
Where or how can I change a window button item on panel icon for a specific application, which is not part of classic Xfce icon?
I need change this:

[image: this]

to this:

[image: this].

**What I did:**
I tried to add the icon to theme in home folder.

```
~/.icon/THEME
```

I tried edit this file in theme folder.

```
index.theme
```

But it doesn't work. Maybe I did something wrong? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I figure this should work in every xfce, this case is Debian xfce:

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello @guillermo, thank you, but this is for item "Launcher", I talked about item "Window Buttons".